# grep ignore vim temporary files

Tags: vim, grep, temporary-files

What is the best way to ignore vim temporary files when doing a search with grep?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
grep --exclude=*~
```

I believe that should work.

Comment: Oh, great! I've added `--exclude-dir=.svn` to my `grep` alias in shell profile. I was seeking this solution for ages. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I find [Ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) to be a drop in replacement for my grepping needs. No need to worry about excluding a bunch of file types or directories by default. You can always setup an .ackrc file in order to add more file types or alter ack's default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said this but I suspect that you're grepping through a directory tree.

This may not be the most elegant solution but you might use the output of 'find'.

I often find myself recursively grepping a directory tree like this:

```
grep <needle> `find . \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -print`
```

You could certainly do something like:

```
grep <needle> `find . \! -name '.??*swp' -print`
```

Comment: What do the `\\(` and `\\)` do?

Comment: You should reread markdown parsing rules on SO: it will take something as a block of code if it is indented with *4* spaces and *has an empty line before itself* (really starts a paragraph because at the start of message 4 space indented block without newlines is also taken as code block).